# how to deploy my mern app on render when the project in the same folder?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, render, mern

how to deploy my mern app one i have all project in one folder i mean :
my project folder :

```
=> client // my frontend
=> controllers
=> routers
=> middleware
...
server.js
```

in localhost i use npm run dev in terminal to lunch server, in second terminal i use cd client => npm start to lunch frontend

my server.js :

```
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
  app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

my package.json of server :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

how to deploy it, when i use web service deployement, everything work in server side, but the frontend shows me a white page

thanks